# how to run stored procedure using url

Tags: sql, oracle, notepad++

i created a simple procedure and stored in my sql folder. and i ran this script using command @demo.sql it said procedure created.
now i want to run this script using url but i dont know what is the url for this script.

This script is in this directory.

[image]

This is my script

```
             CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE demo AS
             l_user varchar2(30);
             BEGIN
             select USER into l_user from dual;
             htp.htmlOpen;
             htp.headOpen;
             htp.title('A Very Very Simple Example');
             htp.headClose;
             htp.bodyOpen;
             htp.line;
             htp.header(1,'Simple Example');
             htp.line;
             htp.paragraph;
             htp.print('Today''s date is:  ' ||  to_char(sysdate,     'DD/MM/YYYY'));
             htp.br;
             htp.print('Today''s day  is:  ' ||  to_char(sysdate, 'DAY'));
             htp.paragraph;
             htp.print('Ordinary <em>tags</em> can be used in the strings that we send.');
             htp.print('Your Oracle USERID is ' || l_user);
             htp.line;
             htp.address('Raj Sunderraman');
             htp.bodyClose;
             htp.htmlClose;
             EXCEPTION
             When others Then
             htp.print(SQLERRM);
             htp.bodyClose;
             htp.htmlClose;
             END;
             /
```

Comment: Huh?  Please show something relevant, like what the script does?

Comment: *now i want to run this script* - Surely you have done so - it has created a procedure!

Comment: i am following some tutorial and it said enter this url to run procedure             

http://db.gsu.edu:7777/pls/csc8711/demo

Comment: You are aware you should use the url where your procedure is stored, don't just take the tutorial word for word...The url will be whatever the IP for the box you are connected to over FTP is and then just follow the directory structure you can see in the GUI

Comment: but idont know how to get my url

Comment: Is this not the URL `http://db.gsu.edu:7777/pls/csc8711/demo` as posted previously?

Comment: no, this link was provided in the tutorial

Comment: The script you have run has created the store procedure "demo" in the database. Now you want to access/run this via a web URL through a browser. Where is the web server (HTTP server) mapped to this database database (remote server or on your own PC .. localhost)? Only you can tell us that.  If you installed Oracle and the accompanying web server to your own PC, then most likley you should http://localhost:7777/ as a start then see what information that gives you.